# TFS and Source Control Explorer

Tags: version-control, tfs

In TFS 2005, and when you open from the client side (from VSTS) the source control explorer, and you create a workspace.
Where the data of that workspace is stored?
and is there a command line to get all workspaces and their information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

'tf workspaces' with no /server parameter will read the contents of your local workspace cache, which is stored in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0\Cache\VersionControl.config.  (Change 1.0 -> 2.0 for the TFS 2008).

Running 'tf workspaces' with the /server parameter will wipe out the local cache with fresh data from the server, then return the same information.  This command is handy to know.  If tf commands mysteriously return 'unable to determine the workspace' when you're certain the current directory is mapped, restoring your cache can often help.  This is the case when you switch between VS2005 and VS2008 clients, for instance (since they have independent caches), or when you wipe a machine in such a way that preserves your code but erased your user profile.

The rest of the parameters serve to expand or scope down the query in some way.  Full documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3.aspx